# Is there any way to prevent table from updating?

Tags: oracle, plsql

As mentioned in the title, is it possible to prevent the data in the table from being updated?
I tried using the following trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER block_payment_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON payment  
DECLARE 
e_no_update_allowed EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    RAISE e_no_update_allowed;
    EXCEPTION WHEN e_no_update_allowed THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Updating PAYMENT table is not allowed');
END;
```

I know that `LOCK TABLE statement` with `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` can be used, but is there a possibility that it will also block inserting data to a table?

Comment: You could remove `UPDATE` permissions on the database. :) `REVOKE UPDATE ON payment`

Comment: In your trigger, you raise an exception, capture it, print a message, then let the update continue. If you want to abort the update, you need to raise an exception again after the dbms_output. But, as others mentioned, you may be able to do it by revoking grants.

Answer (score 5):

Like the buddy who comment, you can `REVOKE` update privileges in your database, here is an example.

```
REVOKE UPDATE ON table to <username>
```

Information that might be useful:

**GRANT creates a permission rule**

**REVOKE removes a permission rule**